# "Unable to access jarfile" window command

Tags: java, jar, command

I am trying to create a .jar-file. Using Eclipse i generated a jar-file but it is not working the way i want.

So i searched on the web and i found a solution:

```
 create a file from the window command!!!
```

I tried bu its still not working although a made everything! :(

When i run from the command i receive the following error:

[image]

Hier the content Manifest.txt:

```
Main-Class: main.testclass
Class-Path: lib/dom4j-1.5.jar lib/jdom.jar lib/xmlbeans-2.4.0.jar lib/ooxml-schemas-1.0.jar
```

sample.jar is the jar file i want to create , the Manifest.txt contains the dependencies for my class.

Can someone please tell me what i am doing wrong?

Thanks you!

PS: I am using windwo xp

Comment: You probably have no access rights in that directory path.

Comment: Is your sample.jar in a \test directory?  Also Manifest file should be inside your jar file.

Comment: yes everything is in the same directory

Comment: when you export with eclipse what's wrong? maybe i can help you.

Comment: @ZaoTaoBao it is now working with eclipse! But not on my computer but on colleagues computer!

Comment: yeah! together always better!

Answer (score 2):

Use the jar command for creating JARs - The `java -jar` syntax is for running JAR files

```
jar -cf sample.jar Manifest.txt /path/to/*.class
```

where `/path/to` is the path to the class files contained in `sample.jar`

Comment: You need to have a JDK installed

Comment: sure i have jdk and jre6

Comment: Ensure the JDK bin dir is on your path

Comment: `path=<path to jdk>\bin;%PATH`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39747/discussion-between-reimeus-and-lisa)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you run cmd as administrator ?

r-click on cmd and choose run as administrator.

Comment: Since when is creating a jar an administrative task?

Comment: it happened with me before on windows 7. when i tried to create a jar file in C partition .

Answer (score 0):

try to do it in this way!
[export](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uo0n4.jpg)
[image: kind of file]
[image: select what you wanna and destination]

Remember to leave in your documents or someplace like you have permissions!, if you aren't administrator.In the second picture is important select what you wanna have inside jar.

Comment: Thanks but i alrady tried on this way. It is working! Now i just want to learn how to do it from the window command! It seem i have rights problems...
Thank you anyway :)

Comment: don't worry.. I do it for fun..if you want to package in trendiness way i encourage to you try to learn maven!